# Is it possible to develop IOS application without a Mac via Intel XDK/Phonegap?

Tags: android, ios7, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

I am planning to build an application for both Android and iOS, but from what I've heard, using Phonegap framework it's not possible to develop and deploy an iOS application **only** using Windows.

Is this true? Will I need a Mac for deployment? Any suggestions will help me proceed.

Regards

Comment: You can use PhoneGap Build to compile your iOS PhoneGap application without running OS X on your development machine.

Comment: intel XDK is built over phonegap, so you have the same limitations. The only option is as @CommonsWare told you, use phonegap build, but you still need to generate your certificates, that is possible without a mac, but a bit harder

Answer (score 3):

**YES**, It is possible to develop and test app for iOS using [**Intel XDK**](http://xdk.intel.com) on Windows. However you still need a Mac when you are ready to submit app to Apple AppStore. But you can do development, create certificate and test on iOS device without a Mac.